# VueJS dynamically update v-html content

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I'm trying to update a v-html binding using JS but I seem to be a bit stuck.
Could anyone help?

The idea of the code is that I have a list of items per page. And I want to create a pagination. Where the pagination numbers represent the ***current_page***

The problem is that I'm trying to update the page number but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've added this inside a jsfilde

```js
var configuration = {
  searchableFields: ['title', 'tags', 'actors'],
  sortings: {
    name_asc: {
      field: 'name',
      order: 'asc'
    }
  },
  aggregations: {
    tags: {
      title: 'Tags',
      size: 10
    },
    actors: {
      title: 'Actors',
      size: 10
    },
    genres: {
      title: 'Genres',
      size: 10
    }
  }
}

// the rows comes from external resources
// https://github.com/itemsapi/itemsapi-example-data/blob/master/jsfiddle/imdb.js
itemsjs = itemsjs(rows, configuration);
var per_page = 3;
var current_page = 1;

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#el',
  data: function() {

    // making it more generic
    var filters = {};
    Object.keys(configuration.aggregations).map(function(v) {
      filters[v] = [];
    })

    return {
      query: '',
      // initializing filters with empty arrays
      filters: filters,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reset: function() {
      var filters = {};
      Object.keys(configuration.aggregations).map(function(v) {
        filters[v] = [];
      })

      this.filters = filters;
      this.query = '';
    }
  },
  computed: {
    searchResult: function() {

      var result = itemsjs.search({
        query: this.query,
        filters: this.filters,
        per_page: per_page,
        page: current_page
      })
      return result
    }
  }
});

var content = "";
var active = "";
var total = document.getElementById("pagination__total").value;
var num_pages = Math.ceil(total / per_page);
console.log(num_pages);
for (var i = 1; i <= num_pages; i++) {
  active = current_page == i ? "is-current" : "";
  content += `<li class="pagination-link is-size-6 ${active}" data-page="${i}">${i}</li>`;
}
document.querySelector(".pagination-list").innerHTML = content;
content = "";


let pagination = document.querySelectorAll(".pagination-link");
for (let i = 0; i < pagination.length; i++) {
  pagination[i].addEventListener("click", ev => {
    current_page = ev.target.getAttribute("data-page");
    console.log(current_page);
    vm.searchResult.page = current_page;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/itemsapi/itemsjs/master/dist/itemsjs.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/itemsapi/itemsapi-example-data/master/jsfiddle/imdb.js"></script>
<div id="el">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" v-on:click="reset()">ItemsJS movies</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" v-model="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">

    <input type="hidden" v-bind:value="searchResult.pagination.total" id="pagination__total">
    <input type="hidden" v-bind:value="searchResult.pagination.page" id="pagination__curent-page">
    <h1>List of items ({{ searchResult.pagination.total }})</h1>

    <p class="text-muted">Search performed in {{ searchResult.timings.search }} ms, facets in {{ searchResult.timings.facets }} ms</p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
        <div v-for="facet in searchResult.data.aggregations">
          <h5 style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><strong style="color: #337ab7;" v-html="facet.title"></strong></h5>

          <ul class="browse-list list-unstyled long-list" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
            <li v-for="bucket in facet.buckets">
              <div class="checkbox block" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
                <label>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" v-model="filters[facet.name]" v-bind:value="bucket.key">
                {{ bucket.key }} ({{ bucket.doc_count }}) 
              </label>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
        <div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <!--<h3>List of items ({{ searchResult.pagination.total }})</h3>-->
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="item of searchResult.data.items">
              <td><img style="width: 100px;" v-bind:src="item.image"></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <b v-html="item.name"></b>
                <br />
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <nav class="pagination is-centered" aria-label="pagination">
        <div>
          <i class="pagination-previous is-size-6 fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>
          <ul class="pagination-list"></ul>
          <i class="pagination-next is-size-6 fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, you should not update computed value like that.

Comment: what would be the alternative way to do it?

Comment: please post [mcve], with script execution order.

Comment: @appleapple I've updated the code and added a link to jsfiddle. Could you have another look, please?

Comment: I've post an answer, but since your code is too long, I just make a guess, please try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply put `current_page` inside `data`

```
...
var vm = new Vue({
  data: function() {
    ...
    return {
      query: '',
      current_page,
      filters: filters
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

---

then use `vm.current_page` instead of `current_page`

```
pagination[i].addEventListener("click", ev => {
  vm.current_page = ev.target.getAttribute("data-page");
  console.log(vm.current_page);
});
```

and

```
searchResult: function() {

  var result = itemsjs.search({
    query: this.query,
    filters: this.filters,
    per_page: per_page,
    page: this.current_page // <-----
  })
  return result
}
```

Comment: @Selyst no problem :)